# Eclipse c++ How to work with existing makefile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I'm a newbie  and I've a problem!
I've to work with a c++ code  and I don't know how to import it and how to compile it on eclips ( I compiled it by command line).
The code has a particular structure and it is organized in this way:

```
repos____lib____configure (execute the configure file inside the libraries folders)
                  I           I___makefile (execute the make file inside the libraries folders,
                                                        requires make/make.def)
      I           I___ib1____.cpp
      I           I            I____.h
      I           ...          I____configure (it requires make/configure_lib and
                                                              make/configure_includes
      I           ...          I____makefile (generated by configure)
      I           I___lib2___....
      i           I___.......
      I           I___libn____.cpp
      i                        I____.h
      i                        I____configure
      i                        I____makefile (generated by configure)
      I
      I___make(folder)__bashrc (are set the some environment variables)
      I                               I__configure_bin
      I                               I__configure_includes
      I                               I__configure_lib
      I                               I__make.def (are set all the include path and library path used
      I                                                         in the configure file)
      I___application__main.cpp
                                   I__configure
                                   I__makefile(generated by the configure file)
```

to be sure that you understand my problem...(sure... :) )

the first configure file is:

```
cd lib1; ./configure
cd ../lib2; ./configure
.....
....
cd ../libn; ./configure
cd
```

and the first makefile is

```
include /media/Dati/WORKHOME/repos/make/make.def
```

## this is the makefile for the whole library

```
lib:
    make -C lib1
    make -C lib2
    make -C libn
```

an example of configure file (the one inside lib1):

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

$INC = '$(OPENCVINC) $(FLTKINC) $(DC1394V2INC)';  ##<-DEFINED IN /make.def
$LIB = '$(OPENCVLIB) $(FLTKLIB) $(DC1394V2LIB)';      #####################

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

require '/media/Dati/WORKHOME/repos/make/configure_lib';
print "Created Makefile.\n";

# this will create a include file for the whole directory, 
# using the template <dirname>.h.templ
require '/media/Dati/WORKHOME/repos/make/configure_includes';
print "Created $libname.h\n";
```

compile it without eclipse is simple

1. type /.configure in the lib folder
2. type make
3. go into the application folder
4. type ./configure
5. type make
6. run the program

my question is....in eclipse???
I imported the three with import/ import existing code as makefile project but now I don't know how compile it.
could you please help me? it's important!

thank you very much
gabriele

Comment: +1 for the well-formed and formated question for a person, with 6 rep. (:

Answer (score 1):

You have done the right thing by using "import existing code as makefile project".
Now eclipse know that it needs to call make and use your makefile. But Your build process is not only driven by make.

One solution is to write a makefile that call all your build steps. Something Like :

```
all:
    cd dir1 && ./configure && make
    cd dir2 && ./configure && make 
    etc.
```

my2c

Edit:

I currently have no eclipse installed, so I can not send you detailled steps ... sorry

Comment: @gabriele: that the right way. StackOverflow is different from other forum as it emphasizes well written questions and answers. The way is to comment on question / answers and to edit them if needed. This way you end up with well written and correct answers, not with a lot of comment / reply / answers  ...