# How to autogenerate/add/edit makefiles to a Makefile Project with Existing Code

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-indigo

My Problem is related to this one:
[Eclipse c++ How to work with existing makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368546/eclipse-c-how-to-work-with-existing-makefile)

Basicly i have the same structure (without the configure). I have subfolders like lib1, lib2, lib3 etc... and they each have a makefile. Then I already have one makefile outside of the subfolders that calls my build steps.

What i want to do is add a new subfolder (e.g lib4) and let Eclipse create the makefile for this subfolder and edit the "main" makefile.

I use Eclipse Indigo SR2 for Linux 64Bit.

I wonder if that is even possible for Eclipse or if the makefiles have to be created/edited by hand?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic scenario to use the Autotools. (or write the whole configure script yourself, which can often be simpler.)

I've never used it with Eclipse, but a little search found this:
http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/autotools/